# What is a greenfield project in IT?

Tags: job-search, job-description, terminology

While searching for programmer opportunities, I have come across the term "greenfield project" in many job descriptions.

For example, a job ad may say something like:

> This is a greenfield project utilizing some of the most exciting
>   technologies on the market today.  This is your chance to leave your
>   mark and help us deliver a game changing system [...]

What does it mean to be a greenfield project with respect to IT?

Comment: @DJClayworth - as Oded noted the term is not IT-centric.  There are may types of Greenfield Projects in different industries.  I do not think this is a bad question for the site.

Comment: (edited) If you feel the need to discuss this question, post a question in [meta]. This is on topic because it is a question trying to understand a term in a job posting.  We are striving to become the go to place for people with workplace and job hunting questions. Attacking users because their questions do not pass your definition of a good question is out of line!

Comment: Why was this closed again? Greenfield projects seem definitely on-topic here. Is there another SE site where this question is more on-topic? Then it should've been migrated there. Assuming it's ambiguously on-topic here, I fail to see how closing it helps anyone.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A greenfield project is simply a new project, not building on anything existing. The analogy is to building on a green field - there are no existing buildings or infrastructure.

This is opposed to brownfield projects - which would involve changes and maintenance to an existing piece of work.

The term is not unique to IT.

Comment: For years, i thought it was some sort of environmental contamination designation, seriously!

Comment: @MartinF You're not alone. I've been working on a environmental project for a few years already and just now I've realized it's not a greenfield project.

Answer (score 13):

This obviously **depends on the project and the company** doing it - *everybody has a different notion of 'free of constraints'*.

**Typical** characteristics *can* be:

- no prior project that one has to build on
- no 'legacy' code or data to deal with
- free choice of language, framework, infrastructure
- free choice of programming or management techniques
- no requirements from outside the team
- complete freedom to determine scope with stakeholders
- freedom to pick whoever you want in your team

You get the idea.

Every aspect one might feel constrained by could be removed - *but it doesn't have to, necessarily*. Greenfield projects are designed to **provide a lot of freedom**, but you best **ask the company offering it**, what you are and aren't free to do in such a project.

**Examples**:

- New tools that have not been necessary before
- StartUps
- Prototypes
- Software related to new areas of business a company wants to expand into
- Research projects

Comment: Good answer - but I would point out that while greenfield projects may afford free choice of language, framework, techniques, etc., if it's at the point where the company is hiring developers to work on the project, there's a good chance that those choices have already been made.

Comment: Yes, that may be true.